# How to remove table row from an updated row in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am binding a table using angularjs I have two tabs on a same page In first tab **New** I am inserting data and in tab list I am getting data which have update and delete functionality.

I am attaching the image.

The problem is when I get the edited data then I have to remove the table row which was on a new tab then inserted edited row. How can I do this?
Here is the image:

[image]

Updated row are there:

[image]

I already getting the data but when I used Push method then It is creating newly created row on new tab.

I short My problem is to remove the first row in new tab and inserted the updated row from list tab to new tab.

```
$.each(data.privilegeList, function (i, o) {
                $scope.PrivilegeliST.push({
                    PrivilageId: o.privilegeId, PageName: o.pageName, PageUrl: o.pageUrl, CanView: o.canView, CanEdit: o.canEdit, CanDelete: o.canDelete, CanCreate: o.canCreate
                });
                //$scope.PrivilegeliST.push({ PrivilegeId: o.id, OperatorId: 0, PageName: o.pageName, PageUrl: o.pageUrl, CanEdit: false, CanView: false, CanDelete: false, CanCreate: false });
            });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/UWLFJ/ try like this

Comment: Add more code and this is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just empty the array before push
  `$scope.PrivilegeliST=[]`

then it will replace the updated row